# Pandas:subtract current value with previous value in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'start':[150,1500,1650,1700,1840],'end':[200,1650,1700,1738,1800]})
```

[image]

I am trying to subtract start value from the current row to end value from the previous row and keep adding the subtracted value till the end.

e.g.

2st loop 1500-200

3nd loop 1650-1650 ..

5th loop 1840-1738

Total_subtract = 1402

so far I'm trying it using df.values

```
for x,y in enumerate(audio_output.values):
    print(x,y)
    if (y[2]+1)-(y[2]) >0:
```

I cannot access the previos index to subtract from the current loop.

Is there a way to access the previos index. I have tried in itertuples() in which too I cannot seem to get previous indexes.

Comment: If you rearrange the terms, you see you can do ‘data.iloc[1:,0].sum()-data.iloc[:-1,1].sum()’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[df.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):**

```
In [1906]: (data['start'].shift(-1) - data['end']).sum()
Out[1906]: 1402.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following code.

```
sum(data['start'].iloc[1:].values - data['end'].iloc[:-1].values)
```

Comment: If you use np.sum instead of sum you keep it vectorised